# Why is this low quality review ended?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

[This LQ review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/534610) is no longer available, and I wonder why.

My try:

According to [an answer by one of our mods](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27560/290189), an LQ review will end if the post

- is edited before or from the review
- is closed in case of a question
- is deleted

However, the review target has *neither* been edited *nor* deleted.  What's the reason for the sudden end of the review?

Comment: Here is a bit more detailed description: [When is a post removed from a review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164288) However, I am not sure what caused the review to end. BTW [on the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1553372/timeline) it is marked as invalidated.