# Will a LQ post review end if a person retracts his flag?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts

When I came across [Why is this low quality review ended?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29796/why-is-this-low-quality-review-ended), I immediately came up with a simple explanation: The person who initially flagged the post retracted it! However, this is neither listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-post-removed-from-a-review-queue) nor [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27559/what-clears-a-low-quality-flag-and-what-removes-a-review-from-the-lq-queue). So can it trigger the ending of a review?

---

An additional example of unexpected completion of a review:
[image]

Comment: @BillBollinger I don't see how your comment is related to my question...